# How assign a value to elements of arrays and make a table of mxn containing the values

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I would appreciate if you could help me out with python.

A, B C in this are string in this list.

```
array = ['[A, C]', '[A,B,C]', '[B,C]']

value = [['A', 5],['B', 7],['C', 2]]
```

I want to create a matrix, columns the variable in the list: 'A', 'B', and 'C', and each row would be filled with value of the variable based on their combination in the array. the output, a dataframe, should be created like below:

```
ouput = A  B  C
        5  0  2
        5  7  2
        0  7  2
```

I hope I have been clear about problem. Thanks for any comments and hints.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd
import re

array = ['[A, C]', '[A,B,C]', '[B,C]']
value = [['A', 5],['B', 7],['C', 2]]

# Remove all square brackets and whitespace
# If in real problem there can be something else (not only single letters),
# it's better to use list to avoid false positive matches:
# array = [re.sub(r'\[|\]|\s', '', s).split(',') for s in array]
# (I mean matching 'A' if pattern is '[AB, D]')

values = dict(value)  # for easier iteration

pd.DataFrame([[(v if k in pattern else 0) for k, v in values.items()] 
              for pattern in array], 
             columns=values.keys())
```